# Redundant values in columns with aggregate function?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT
  SUM(total_amt_usd),
  sales_rep_id,
  sales_reps.name AS salesman,
  region.name AS regionname
FROM orders
JOIN accounts
  ON orders.account_id = accounts.id
JOIN sales_reps
  ON accounts.sales_rep_id = sales_reps.id
JOIN region
  ON sales_reps.region_id = region.id
```

Are the three columns redundant with the SUM aggregate function? SUM I believe has correctly performed its operation of summing all the values (total_amt_usd) in the first column.

[image]

Comment: There should be use of GROUP BY with all the non-aggregate SELECT columns.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database engine and version; for example: `postgresql-13` or `mysql-5.7`

Comment: First, some database engines are configured such that if you have an aggregate function in the SELECT statement, then the other non-aggregate columns must appear in a GROUP BY clause. Since that is not the case here, the engine will return you a *single* row containing the sum you are requesting along with an arbitrary row from the rows defined by the FROM clause that would have been returned had you not included the aggregate function in the list of columns being selected. Redundant? I would say "not particularly meaningful."

Comment: 1) tag your database 2) provide sample data and desired output 3) your question is not correct, if sum is returning right number, then you are ok

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT Sum(total_amt_usd), 
   sales_rep_id,
   sales_reps.NAME AS salesman,
   region.NAME     AS regionname
   FROM   orders
   LEFT JOIN accounts
          ON orders.account_id = accounts.id
   LEFT JOIN sales_reps
          ON accounts.sales_rep_id = sales_reps.id
   LEFT JOIN region
          ON sales_reps.region_id = region.id
   GROUP  BY sales_rep_id,
      sales_reps.NAME,
      region.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

They do not look redundant. It seems like a query to find total sales amount *summed separately* for each sales representative from the orders table. The orders table has the sales representative id, which is used to lookup the representatives name from the joined `sales_reps` table and that table, in turn has a `region_id` which is used to look up region name from the joined `region` table. The final result has rows with `id`, `name`, and `region` of a sales representative along with total amount of orders that sales representative has got.

I think the query should be more like the following for this explanation to make sense:

```
SELECT
  SUM(total_amt_usd),
  sales_rep_id,
  sales_reps.name AS salesman,
  region.name AS regionname
FROM orders
JOIN accounts
  ON orders.account_id = accounts.id
JOIN sales_reps
  ON accounts.sales_rep_id = sales_reps.id
JOIN region
  ON sales_reps.region_id = region.id
GROUP BY sales_rep_id;
```